# Starting namenodes on [ubuntu] ubuntu: ssh: connect to host ubuntu port 22: No route to host

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When i started Namenode using hdfs-dfs.sh, I get error ***Starting namenodes on [ubuntu]
ubuntu: ssh: connect to host ubuntu port 22: No route to host***

Answer (score 1):

1.Please check **core-site.xml** file

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://192.168.203.137:9000</value>
    <description>The name of the default file system.</description>
</property>
```

2. Please check your name node(master node) IP using **ipconfig** command in Ubuntu Terminal

> Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:57:b9:dc
>             inet addr:**192.168.203.137**

3. The above both configuration IP in **core-site.xml**  and Master node IP should be same.
4. Format namenode

> hduser@prasanta$ **hdfs namenode -format**

5. Start dfs

> hduser@prasanta$**start-dfs.sh**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case of a problem with ssh.

Ubuntu: try `sudo service ssh status`

If you get `ssh: unrecognized service`
you should (re)install ssh:

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be problem if you had not added your client ip address into your /etc/hosts file . It is basically problem of ssh. It can be solved by just adding your client ip like these one,
Just move towards your /etc/hosts file and add your namenode or slavenode ip address

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.32 master
192.168.56.133 slave

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And also in your /etc/hostname add these line

```
master
```

Now after that your start-dfs.sh should run .